# SQL COUNT() from other table as condition

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have two tables, for example `user (id, name)` and `user_ban(id,user_id,datetime_banned)`. I need to select all users for which there's no rows in table `user_ban`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `NOT EXISTS` statement in the `WHERE` clause of your query.

Sample:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM User a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM User_Ban b
  WHERE a.id = b.user_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively new but think this will do it. Hope this helps.

SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id NOT IN (SELECT user_ban.user_id FROM user_ban)